# PetShop Dapp error with when compiling and testing adoption.sol but completes anyway

Tags: solidity, truffle

Since the Petshop Dapp was updated earlier this week I noticed an error while compiling and and again whilst testing it seems to be on the adoption.sol file - now it could be something I did in rebuilding the file but just want to ask if anyone else has encountered similar - is this a real error or a warning?

I can see it error both when I compile and test it 
[image]

Here is the solidity code within the adoption.sol file

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Adoption {

    address[16] public adopters;

    function adopt(uint8 petId) public returns (uint8) {
        require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);
        adopters[petId] = msg.sender;
        return petId;
    }

    function getAdopters() public returns (address[16]) {
        return adopters;
    }
}
```

Comment: `is this a real error or a warning?` - the printout says "warning", so it's gotta be a warning, right? BTW, It also tells you what you can do in order to make this warning go away.

Comment: Yeah, probably they just forgot to double-check for warnings before publishing the newest version. You can ignore the warning, it's nothing serious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ignore the warning, its there for a reason. Update your contract to use:

```
function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16]) {
    return adopters;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Vinne, I have rebuilt the code on two different machines and can see i left out the view on the one that was broken - reset everything and all now working as expected thx